# Get data from a table with my foreign key?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently I want to get data from another table with my foreign key.

I have already setup my foreign key.

I have tables setup like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `album` (
  `album_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `album_navn` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`album_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
--

INSERT INTO `album` (`album_ID`, `album_navn`) VALUES
(1, 'Nytår'),
(2, 'Berlin'),
(3, 'Færøerne'),
(5, 'TEST');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `billeder` (
  `billeder_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `billeder_navn` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `billeder_fotograf` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `billeder_sti` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `fk_album_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`billeder_ID`),
  KEY `fk_album_ID` (`fk_album_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=54 ;

--
--

INSERT INTO `billeder` (`billeder_ID`, `billeder_navn`, `billeder_fotograf`, `billeder_sti`, `fk_album_ID`) VALUES
(24, 'Vi tester4', 'Nytår', 'full_nytaar.jpg', 1),
(25, '', 'Nytår', 'full_nytaar2.jpg', 1),
(26, '', 'Nytår', 'full_nytaar4.jpg', 1),
```

Where I want to get ALBUM_NAVN via my fk_album_ID

so it will be possible to get it like this:

$row[album_navn]

I have tried to do it, but im lost.

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Kristian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this query

```
 SELECT * FROM billeder LEFT JOIN album ON billeder.fk_album_ID = album.album_ID
```

Comment: Thanks man that works, but. I need to learn this, would you recommend the tutorials at w3schools for learning this? Or is there other/better ways to learn this. I need 15 reputation to upvote tho ;/

Comment: Please refer this image for study MUSQL JOINS [Link to sample](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fiFEO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select * from billeder left join album where billeder.fk_album_ID=album.album_ID
```

Comment: This is what i have tried..$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM billeder INNER JOIN album ON fk_album_ID = album_navn WHERE album_ID = $id";  but im really struggling learning JOINS and such.

Comment: When i try to do that, i get this Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in... when trying to row[album_navn]

Comment: hmm, but your album_navn is varchar, I think you want join on fk_album_ID = album_ID

Comment: I want it so, I can $row[album_navn] when I have joined fk_album_ID to the other table. just not how sure to "convert" the ID to the album_navn.

Answer (score 0):

This query will bring the desired result.

```
SELECT b . * , a.album_navn FROM  `billeder` b, album a WHERE b.fk_album_ID = a.album_ID
```

Please try this php code  as well. This is working and tested. You need to use join in query.

```
// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
$DB_NAME = 'test';
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '';

$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

    //query
$query = " SELECT b . * , a.album_navn FROM  `billeder` b, album a
    WHERE b.fk_album_ID = a.album_ID";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    // show data
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo ($row['album_navn']);  
    }
}
else {
    echo 'No record found'; 
}

  //close conn
        mysqli_close($mysqli);
```